# Is it possible to find out whether iPhone has MLC or TLC NAND by serial or batch number?

Tags: iphone, flash-memory

Is there any way to check whether the phone has MLC or TLC, just by serial number or batch number?

I will be buying iPhone 6, Space Grey, 64GB. From what I have read, 64GB version could be TLC or MLC.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how/why you think some phones have different NAND? Also - what's the end goal of your question. Would you upgrade to 128 or downgrade to 16 if that was how you got different NAND?

Comment: https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do

Answer (score 1):

You can't figure out the type of NAND from the serial number.
However, Apple is dropping TLC NAND, so it most likely has MLC NAND (however, I can't tell you for sure without you buying it.)